# A limit with sum $S_n=1+\frac{n-1}{n+2}+\frac{n-1}{n+2}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n+3}+\cdots +\frac{n-1}{n+2}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n+3}\cdots \frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: limits

$$S_n=1+\frac{n-1}{n+2}+\frac{n-1}{n+2}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n+3}+\cdots     +\frac{n-1}{n+2}\cdot \frac{n-2}{n+3}\cdots \frac{1}{2n}$$ Then $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ tends to $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

How to show then? The general term in $S_n$ is $$\frac{n-1}{n+2}\frac{n-2}{n+3}\cdots \frac{n-k}{n+k+1}=\frac{C_{n+1}^{k+2}}{C_{n+k+1}^{k+2}}$$ where $C_n^k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Then how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logarithm of a term is roughly
$$\int_{n-k-\frac12}^{n-\frac12}\log t dt - \int_{n+\frac32}^{n+k+\frac32}\log t dt$$
Find the leading order behaviour of that, then approximate the sum $S_n by an integral.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$S_n=\frac{1}{C_{2n}^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}C_{2n}^{n+k+1}=\frac{1}{2C_{2n}^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(C_{2n}^{n+k+1}+C_{2n}^{n-k-1}\right)=\frac{2^{2n-1}}{C_{2n}^{n+1}}-\frac{n+1}{2n}$$
By Stirling's approximation,
$$C_{2n}^{n+1}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n-1)!(n+1)!}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{2^{2n}}{(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n-\frac{1}{2}}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sim \frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
Hence
$$\lim\frac{S_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$